# Nginx proxy_pass : Is it possible to add a static parameter to the URL?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to add a parameter in the URL in a proxy pass.
For example, I want to add an apiKey : &apiKey=tiger
http://mywebsite.com/oneapi?field=22 ---> https://api.somewhere.com/?field=22&apiKey=tiger 
Do you know a solution ?

Thank's a lot,
Gilles.

```
server {
      listen   80;
      server_name  mywebsite.com;
      location /oneapi{
      proxy_pass         https://api.somewhere.com/;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
location = /oneapi {
  set $args $args&apiKey=tiger;
  proxy_pass https://api.somewhere.com;
}
```

Comment: If $args is empty you set $args to ?&apiKey=tiger. It's not right.

Comment: In facts, I validated too fast your answer and the edited solution worked. In the question $args isn't empty => ?field=22&apiKey=tiger

Comment: This does not appear to work when using a `location /somepath` block (no equals sign). I had to use `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?$args&myParam=value break;` instead at the same spot.

Comment: great solution, but see my solution if you want it to work when $args is empty

Comment: This is not cleanest way. Please take a look mine.

Answer (score 17):

**The other answers do not work if `$args` is empty.**

This also works if `$args` is empty.

```nginx
location /oneapi {
  set $delimeter "";

  if ($is_args) {
    set $delimeter "&";
  }

  set $args "$args${delimeter}apiKey=tiger";

  proxy_pass https://api.somewhere.com/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot :D :D

Comment: This is not cleanest way. Please take a look mine.

Answer (score 4):

github gist https://gist.github.com/anjia0532/da4a17f848468de5a374c860b17607e7

```nginx
    #set $token "?"; # deprecated

    set $token ""; # declar token is ""(empty str) for original request without args,because $is_args concat any var will be `?`

    if ($is_args) { # if the request has args update token to "&"
        set $token "&";
    }

    location /test {
        set $args "${args}${token}k1=v1&k2=v2"; # update original append custom params with $token
        # if no args $is_args is empty str,else it's "?"
        # http is scheme
        # service is upstream server
        #proxy_pass http://service/$uri$is_args$args; # deprecated remove `/`
        proxy_pass http://service$uri$is_args$args; # proxy pass
    }

    #http://localhost/test?foo=bar ==> http://service/test?foo=bar&k1=v1&k2=v2

    #http://localhost/test/ ==> http://service/test?k1=v1&k2=v2
```

Comment: the answer would be better if you explained the code and the reason for it.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, my english is not very good , but i am working on it. I will improve my answer.

Comment: Close, but here when `$args` is empty, `http://localhost/test/` will actually redirect to `http://service/test??k1=v1&k2=v2` (two integorrations signs), which seems to be caused by nginx turning `$is_args` to `?` when concatenating to another string, even if empty. Removing `$is_args` from the final statement in turn will cause `$args` to lack the preceding token when not empty.

Comment: if `$args` is empty,the `$token` is `?` ,so ` set $args "${args}${token}k1=v1&k2=v2"` you'll get empty str+`?`+custom params. if `$args` is not empty ,the `$token` is `&`, the `L8` code is `?old args`+`&`+custom params.

Comment: @Mahn the nginx's doc http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args `?” if a request line has arguments, or an empty string otherwise`

Comment: if `$args` is empty,the `$is_args` is `empty string`,so `$token` is `?`, so `http://service/$uri$is_args$args` eq `http://service/$uri$tokenk1=v1&k2=v2` eq `http://service/$uri?k1=v1&k2=v2`. if `$args` is not empty,the `$is_args` is `?`,so `$token` is `&`, so `http://service/$uri$is_args$args` eq `http://service/$uri?$args$tokenk1=v1&k2=v2` eq `http://service/$uri?$args&k1=v1&k2=v2`.

Comment: @AnJia I understand what you were trying to do, but in my real life tests the nginx documentation appears to be wrong, `$is_args` is never empty when concatenated to another string. Test it yourself if you'd like.

Comment: @Mahn yeah, u r right, i'll modify my anwser. i create a github gist https://gist.github.com/anjia0532/da4a17f848468de5a374c860b17607e7

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to add a paramater in nginx when it's unknown whether the original URL had arguments or not (i.e. when you have to account for both `?` and `&`):

```
location /oneapi {
    set $pretoken "";
    set $posttoken "?";

    if ($is_args) {
        set $pretoken "?";
        set $posttoken "&";
    }

    # Replace apiKey=tiger with your variable here
    set $args "${pretoken}${args}${posttoken}apiKey=tiger"; 

    # Optional: replace proxy_pass with return 302 for redirects
    proxy_pass https://api.somewhere.com$uri$args; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone get here. Thanks for https://serverfault.com/questions/912090/how-to-add-parameter-to-nginx-query-string-during-redirect

The cleanest way on 2021 is:

```
rewrite ^ https://api.somewhere.com$uri?apiKey=tiger permanent;
```

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them

### proxy_pass way

```
upstream api {
    server api.somewhere.com;
}

location /oneapi {
    rewrite ^/oneapi/?(.*) /$1?apiKey=tiger break;
    proxy_pass https://api$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Redirect & proxy are two different things. Try googling "redirect vs proxy".

Comment: @Lukman They can be used together. Try googling "rewrite proxy_pass together".

Comment: This is the correct and most flexible way in  terms of query parameters