# How can Nginx add the Subdomain as parameter when a proxy_pass to Tomcat is executed

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, dns, wildcard-subdomain

**What I am trying to achieve**
The web application should be able to support multiple subdomains without having to make any changes on the nginx or tomcat every time a new subdomain is used. (I have already done the required changes to DNS to support wild card subdomains)

Nginx listens to port 80. It does a proxy_pass to tomcat at port 8080.
nginx should be able to support multiple subdomain.

**My current setup is based on this answer. But it is not passing the parameter** 
[Nginx proxy_pass : Is it possible to add a static parameter to the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532293/nginx-proxy-pass-is-it-possible-to-add-a-static-parameter-to-the-url)

**Every possible subdomain**
dynamic_subdomain_1.localhost
dynamic_subdomain_2.localhost

**nginx setup**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.localhost$;

    location / {
        set $args ?$args&site=$subdomain;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Nginx should append the subdomain as a parameter when it invokes Tomcat.

**The Calls to Tomcat should be as follows for each subdomain**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080?site=dynamic_subdomain_1
http://127.0.0.1:8080?site=dynamic_subdomain_2
```

I have tried the above setup but the query parameter always shows up as null.

What should I change in nginx to make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is little bit simpler than that. Just get the substring with the subdomain and use it as a parameter for proxy_pass:

```
server {                                                         
  # this matches every subdomain of domain.
  server_name .domain;                                           

  location / {                                                   
    set $new_request_uri "";                                     
    set $subdomain "";

    if ($host ~* "^(.+)\.domain$") {                             
      set $subdomain $1;                                         
      # lets assume there are args...
      set $new_request_uri "$request_uri&subdomain=$subdomain";  
    }                                                            
    # if there are no args add a question mark and the subdomain argument
    if ($args = '') {                                            
      set $new_request_uri "$request_uri?subdomain=$subdomain";  
    }                                                            

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$new_request_uri;              
  }                                                              
}
```

I considered the request with or without args. I think it solves yout problem.

Alfredo